# T-SQL Procedure parameter name

Tags: t-sql

I have to create a procedure with same parameters names as excel columns. Some loook like this 'xxx/xxx' or 'xxx - xxx'. Is there any work around to name parameteres in a stored procedure like this?

Comment: I bet you can alias those fields using quotes similar to --> SELECT 'xxx - xxx'=MyFieldName

Comment: I tried "@IMEISN as 'IMEI/SN'  nvarchar(100)"    " @IMEISN   nvarchar(100) as 'IMEI/SN' ,"  and none works

Answer (score 0):

Forward slash (/) or dash (-) are not allowed in variable names

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx, that means that the allowed characters are:

- Letters as defined in the Unicode Standard 3.2. The Unicode
  definition of letters includes Latin characters from a through z,
  from A through Z, and also letter characters from other languages.
- Decimal numbers from either Basic Latin or other national scripts.
- The at sign (@), dollar sign ($), number sign (#), or underscore (_).

Answer (score 0):

Okay first of all why would you ever want to use special characters?  That is like saying I want to fry toast underwater with electricity, why can't I have an outlet to allow that?  Special characters denote special things and as such many engines, not just in SQL, but most languages will not allow reserved characters for use in variables. The best you could do was put in parameters with the reversed '_' and then replace that AFTER the object was already created for echoing out.  The placeholder name of '@(something)' is really arbitrary and could be @X or @LookAtMe.  It's type is important to form a contract that must be fulfilled for execution but the naming is really for hooking up.  Having said that if you just must have these weird names echoed out you could do something like this:

```
CREATE PROC pSimpleParam @My_Param INT
AS 
SELECT @My_Param
GO

ALTER PROC pSimpleParam @My_Param INT
AS 
SELECT
  pr.name AS ParameterName
, REPLACE(pr.name, '_', '-') AS AlteredParameterName
FROM sys.procedures p
  INNER JOIN sys.parameters pr ON pr.object_id = p.object_id
    AND p.name = 'pSimpleParam'
GO
```